# Network Namespaces security issues

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, security, root

So I created a network namespace for running a vpn only for selected applications, let's call it "myvpn".

I understand I need root to set a different namespace, which by default will start any command that comes next with such privilege, so I ran sudo -u to change to a my unprivileged user and then I execute a bash shell.

```
sudo ip netns exec myvpn sudo -u $(whoami) /bin/bash
```

It works fine, but my question is: Can it be considered a significant security issue? Is there any feasible way an attacker can take advantage of this situation to gain root access from that very same unprivileged shell if I used for, let's say, running an irc client or any other program with network capabilities?

I know going online is a risk by itself and that no system is really safe at all times, but I'm talking about more specific risks related to the scenario just described.

Thanks for you time and please excuse any misspellings, I'm having a hard time with english. Bye!

Comment: Your unprivileged user account seems to have sudo rights.